Unity - Run a background task
i need to have a running app in Unity in background?
Running this on awake, it will only work for desktop
Application.runInBackground = true;
but it does not work for applications. Any Suggestions?
Tips: It can be checked using Unity logcat. For example you can print a message "Hello World!" , you should be able to read it while app is minimized (/ screen off possibly)
What i have tried is to build an background service. Here is how to set it up:
Go set the Package Name into your

edit - > project settings - >player - > android - > other settings
"com.your.example"

into your project there is the android manifest, if not ,
Assets\Plugins\Android

edit - > project settings - >player - > android - > publish settings
-> check custom android manifest

then create folders

\Android\com\your\example

and there place these scripts
BootReceiver.java
https://pastebin.com/MPbfZr01
LocationPlugin.java
https://pastebin.com/3vs0HyDf
ServiceMessageReceiver.java
https://pastebin.com/S4vZEGEa
StatusCheckStarter.java
https://pastebin.com/cPrnx9R0
in case you need to include on that foreground service an incon you need to place it right here in PNG
\your\example\res\drawable
but also needs some more stuff to be done with android studio but i have not managed to do that yet (need aar file compressed). Any solution to that is also welcomed
and finally android manifest
AndroidManifest.xml
https://pastebin.com/jP8usZfP
that manifest also includes information about the top bar to make it solid and visible when app is open. That was also an issue i had and the only solution i found so i can see time ,battery etc when app open)
and from unity side place this into a gameobject
PluginWrapper.cs
https://pastebin.com/RYc9E4fi
In case you change your package name you need to change it from all the scripts "com.yourother.examples"

Did you read the reference? Android: This property works in Android only if the application is visible, but not when it's in focused state. For example, when the app is run in multi-window mode, such as Samsung Dex and Oculus Quest 2. If the application is running in background, it pauses regardless of the Application.runInBackground option. If you want to execute tasks while it is in background, you need to implement the background service.

Yes i tried that but i stuck, not able to run code from unity but able to run debug logs into the screen.

@shingo edited the answer to what i have tried

The reference means that when the app is in background, all C# code will not work, and everything you need to do must be done in the background service.

I am subscribed to a MQTT topic, and when i receive a message it print logs even with screen closed and i am able to view to log printed via the logcat.  I used an async void Start() and then my function is also an async Task , and inside that i have UnityMainThreadDispatcher.Instance().Enqueue(() =>
without that i could not update data on the ui, it was lagging for some reason but the fun fact it is that it works in background. All my other code is not the same setup so that is why i see this only in that part



    
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;
using System.Threading;



public class BackgroundNumberDisplay : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Assigned in Inspector")]
    public TextMeshProUGUI numberText;
    private int currentNumber = 0;
    private Thread backgroundThread;
    private bool keepRunning = true;

    void Start()
    {
        Application.runInBackground = true;

        // Ensure UnityMainThreadDispatcher is created on the main thread
        UnityMainThreadDispatcher.Instance();

        if (numberText != null)
        {
            numberText.text = currentNumber.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("TextMeshProUGUI component not assigned!");
        }

        // Start the background thread
        backgroundThread = new Thread(BackgroundUpdate);
        backgroundThread.Start();
    }

    void BackgroundUpdate()
    {
        // Increment the counter every second in the background
        while (keepRunning)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            currentNumber++;            
            Debug.Log("Current Num:" + currentNumber);
            // Use the UnityMainThreadDispatcher to update the UI
            UnityMainThreadDispatcher.Instance().Enqueue(() =>
            {
                if (numberText != null)
                {                
                    numberText.text = currentNumber.ToString();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        // Stop the background thread when the application quits
        keepRunning = false;
        backgroundThread.Join();
    }


That worked for me using threads




Jim, could you add a brief explanation to your code? This makes it more useful for future readers.

This script updates a TextMeshProUGUI component with an incrementing number in the background using a separate thread.
Start(): Initializes the UI, enables running in the background, and starts the background thread.
BackgroundUpdate(): Increments currentNumber every second and updates the UI using UnityMainThreadDispatcher to ensure thread-safe UI updates.
OnApplicationQuit(): Stops the background thread when the application closes.

The UnityMainThreadDispatcher ensures UI changes are made on the main thread, as Unity doesn’t support UI updates from background threads.
